# Microsoft SQL Server join get second table options in one column with delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table called `Products` and a second table called `Colors`.

There's a FK `productId` in both tables.

`Color` table look like this:

```
colorId | productId | color
---------------------------
1       | 10        | Red
2       | 10        | Yellow
3       | 10        | Green
```

How could I do a join in order to get all colors associated to `productId = 10` all in a single row with comma delimiter?

I mean the result should look like:

```
prodId | ProdName  | Colors 
-----------------------------
10     |Man t-Short|Red, Green,Yellow
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate the values into a single column:

```
select distinct p.prodid, p.prodname,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + c.color
         from Colors c
         where p.prodId = c.productid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') colors
from products p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65991/2).

Or you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select p.prodid, 
  p.prodname,
  left(colors, len(colors)-1) colors
from products p
cross apply
(
  select c.color + ', '
  from colors c
  where p.prodid = c.productid
  for xml path('')
) c (colors);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65991/7)